# Why is this copyin statement for sqlx hanging?

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I've written a toy app to experiment with using Postgresql through sqlx.  I got a mass insert working using

```
pq.CopyIn
```

as content of a prepared statement

```
stmt, _ := tx.Preparex(pq.CopyIn(tablename, column, column, ...)
```

I would then proceed to add rows to the mass insert I'm creating.

```
tx.Exec(..., ..., ...)
```

then finally execute the prepared statement

```
stmt.Exec()
```

This worked perfectly before, but now I've come back to it and try and execute this code, it hangs on the

```
stmt.Exec
```

Am I missing something in my code or is this all to do with the Database Engine, being unresponsive.

Here's my full code for this.

```
package main

import (
    _ "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var schema = `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact (
        id Serial,
        first_name text,
        last_name text,
        email text
);`

type Contact struct {
    Id int            `json:"-"`
    First_name string `json:"first_name"`
    Last_name string  `json:"last_name"`
    Email string      `json:"email"`
}

type Contacts struct {
    Contacts []Contact `json:"contacts"`
}

func (c *Contacts) createFromJSON(json_str []byte) error {
    b := []byte(json_str)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return err
}

func (c *Contacts) save(db *sqlx.DB) error {
    tx := db.MustBegin()

    stmt, _ := tx.Preparex(pq.CopyIn("contact", "first_name", "last_name", "email"))

    for _, contact := range c.Contacts {
        tx.Exec(contact.First_name, contact.Last_name, contact.Email)

    }

    _, err := stmt.Exec()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }
    err = stmt.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }

    tx.Commit()

    return nil
}

func connect() (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=pqgotest dbname=pqgotest sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db, err
}


func createTables(db *sqlx.DB) {
    db.MustExec(schema)
}


func main() {
    db, err := connect()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    createTables(db)
    contactsJson, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./contacts.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", e)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    tx := db.MustBegin()
    tx.MustExec("DELETE FROM contact")
    tx.Commit()

    contacts := new(Contacts)

    contacts.createFromJSON(contactsJson)

    contacts.save(db)

    people := new(Contacts)
    db.Select(people.Contacts, "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY email,id ASC")

    for _, contact := range people.Contacts {
        contact_json, err := json.Marshal(contact)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", contact_json)
    }


}
```

I could include the contents of the contacts.json file as well, if that will help.

UPDATE

Yes it was obvious in the end.  I was creating a statement from tx,

```
stmt, _ := tx.Preparex(pq.CopyIn(tablename, column, column, ...)
```

and further additions to this should be to stmt

```
stmt.Exec(..., ..., ...)
```

Also another error not directly related to the question is where I insert an array of contacts into the Contacts field of the struct Contacts

```
people := new(Contacts)
db.Select(people.Contacts, "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY email,id ASC")
```

should be passing a pointer to the Select method of db of the Contacts array field of Contacts, like so

```
db.Select(&people.Contacts, "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY email,id ASC")
```

In case people try and run this code later and wonder why it's not printing the results to the console.

Comment: Getting `pq: syntax error at or near "STDIN"` for `tx.Preparex(pq.CopyIn(...))`

Comment: That doesn't mean that much to me. Maybe there's a copy error in the copied code. It's been almost a year since I asked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Bulk imports part in https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq, it should be

```
stmt.Exec(contact.First_name, contact.Last_name, contact.Email)
```